# Properly Throw an Error from an Axios Call

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, axios

I have a two applications (appA, appB). A calls B

AppA endpoint is

```
    api.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
        return axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3060/api/"
        }).then((data) => {
            return data.data
        }).catch((err) => {
            const {config, request, response} = err
            let e = new Error(`Rethrowing the "${"B"}" error FROM A`)
            e.stack?.split('\n').slice(0,2).join('\n') + '\n' + response.data;
            throw e
        })
    });
```

AppB is:

```
    api.get('/', (req, res) => {
        throw new Error('B')
    });
```

My Goal is to Append the error from AppB to a new Error in AppA and send it to who ever is calling AppA. When I try throwing an error from the axios call The error prints in the console and says `nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Rethrowing the "B" error FROM A`. And the Endpoint just times out.

How can I properly throw the Appended Error from the Axios Catch? I'd like to send the stack trace with the error message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send error response from your AppB

```
api.get('/', (req, res) => {
       res.status(500).send('send your error')
});
```

Now when you make call from your AppA and if you receive error from AppB

```
      that error directly throw to catch block of your AppA 

    // AppA
    .catch((err) => {
       //you will receive your AppB error here if you set status code as 500 or any other error status code 
    })
```

There is two possibilities in your case :

Error from  AppA /  AppB

If you are getting error from `AppA` then you can Throw your error and send response to your user from catch block

Else if you are getting error from `AppB` then you can send response with status code 500 means error from server to your `AppA` So, your AppA will directly get this error in catch block as error because of 500 status code and your AppA going to send error to your user directly.

Comment: let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, so if I want to send the stack trace I can't use the Error object?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the error like this:

```
 api.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
        return axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3060/api/"
        }).then((data) => {
            return data.data
        }).catch((err) => {
           let errorStack = new Error(err);
           res.status(500).send(errorStack.toString()) // This will send the error stack
        })
    });
```